# jQuery appended elements not showing without page refresh

Tags: jquery, append

I do not have much experience with jQuery. I am trying to get appended buttons to appear on a page. The user types something into the search bar, it gets added to an array in local storage which will then generate buttons. However, it does not work and I am not sure why. When I refresh the page they show up. They do not appear in the html either until the page is refreshed.

I have tried moving the code I tried using location.reload() but this does not work. I do not know where to start. I have included the relevant part of the code I think.

```
btnIcon.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var searchInput = document.querySelector("#search-input").value;
    console.log(searchInput)

    if (!cities.includes(searchInput)) {
        cities.push(searchInput)
        localStorage.setItem("cities", JSON.stringify(cities))

    }

    queryURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + searchInput + apiKey;
    getWeather(queryURL);
})

for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {

    var button = $("<button>").text(cities[i]).attr("id", cities[i]).on("click", function () {
        console.log(this)
        queryURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + $(this).attr("id") + apiKey;

        getWeather(queryURL);

    })

    $("#history").prepend(button)


}
```

Comment: You only store the "city" in `localStorage` but you're not adding a `<button>`. Put the body of the loop into its own function and call it in the `click` handler when you store the new city in `localStorage`

Comment: I did this function addButton() {
    var button = $("<button>").text(cities[i]).attr("id", cities[i]).on("click", function () {
        console.log(this)
        queryURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + $(this).attr("id") + apiKey;

        getWeather(queryURL);

    })

    $("#history").prepend(button)
}

It works sometimes, but sometimes it creates a button with the previous search term, not the current. And sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Could you tell me why did you ```prepend``` function instead of ```append``` function? And could you share the html code also?

Comment: I used prepend because I wanted the newest entry to appear at the top of the buttons.